# Jquery / Javascript array questions and answer

Tags: image, linq-to-xml

So I have this movie review website. I am using Linq to XML to get a movie review element and its contents (Title, Review and rating). The rating comes from a dropdownlist, and the following code:

```
var rating = "";
for (int i = 0; i < (int)film.Element("rating"); i++)
{
    rating += "<img src='../bilder/star.png'/>";
}
```

Prints images equal to the value chosen in the dropdownlist. Now to the problem. I am sending this in as an assignment, so i have to .zip the website folder to send it in. When i copy the website folder, put it into another folder on the desktop and try to run it, it gives me no images. Just blank/broken document images equal to the amount chosen in the dropdown list, it is not getting the star.png image right, even if i have this in a file called images/star.png.

Anyone have any solution to this?

Comment: But it seems to be searching for ../bilder/star.png not images/star.png  Could this just be a typo?  Does the image appear on your website if you pull up the page, and then replace the file name in the URL with ../bilder/star.png?

Comment: Yeah woops, sorry about that...hehe. bilder = images in norwegian:)I try to use both /bilder/star.png and ~/bilder/star.png, but does not seem to work either:/

Comment: Can you view the image on your website from the browser?

Comment: Yes, localy i can. But if i copy the website, and try to run that, it seem that it cant find the image source or something. It is displaying the number of images (if working correclty, showing stars) that is chosen from the dropdownlist. Cant seem to get my head around this one =S